# Cannot get the list of subscriptions from Azure AD using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get the list of notification subscriptions from Azure AD using Microsoft graph api.

I am trying it in a webjob application.

The funtions class in the Webjob project has a code like

```
  public static void CreateAndUpdateSubcriptions()
    {
        var config= new ConfigurationSettings
        {
            AppId = "*****",
            AppSecret = "***",
            Ngrok = "****",
            TenantId = "*****"
        };

        var graphServiceClient = GetGraphClient(config);//creates the graph client using client credential flow

        var subscriptions = graphServiceClient.Subscriptions
            .Request()
            .GetAsync().Result;

        List<Subscription> subscription = new List<Subscription>();

        foreach (var subscrip in subscriptions)
        {
            if (subscrip.NotificationUrl == config.Ngrok + "/api/notifications")
            {
                subscription.Add(subscrip);
            }
        }

        if (subscription.Count == 0)
        {
            var s = new Subscription
            {
                ChangeType = "updated",
                NotificationUrl = config.Ngrok + "/api/notifications",
                Resource = "groups",
                ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
                ClientState = "****"
            };
            s = graphServiceClient
                    .Subscriptions
                    .Request()
                    .AddAsync(sub).Result;

        }
        else
        {
            CheckSubscriptions(subscription, config);
        }
    }
```

I have given the application the delegated permission(Subscription.Read.All).

But I am not getting any subscriptions back from the section of the code when I am running the code again(so there is a subscription which exists),

```
var subscriptions = graphServiceClient.Subscriptions
            .Request()
            .GetAsync().Result;
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

You should give the application the **application permission** instead of **delegated permission**.

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-permissions-and-consent#types-of-permissions

Also remember to click grant admin consent button.

**Updates:** refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs).
[image]

Comment: thank you but there is no permission called Subscription.Read.All under application permissions

Comment: Have you created the subscription successfully?

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you are able to create subscriptions, you do not require any special permissions beyond the ones the used originally to create its subscriptions.